# Variadic list parameter

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, c

Say I have 2 functions

```
void f1(int p1, int v1, ...);
```

AND

```
void f2(int v1, ...);
```

Inside f1 I want to pass all parameters from variadic list to f2:

```
void f1(int p1, int v1, ...) {
   f2(/*pass all variadic parameters*/);
}
```

For example when I call `f1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`  I want to pass 2,3,4,5 to `f2`

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695982/passing-an-ellipsis-to-another-variadic-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible directly, but you can use the `va_list` type to wrap the full complement of values and pass them to a version of the function that takes such an argument. Basically, break `f2()` into:

```
void f2v(int v1, va_list args) {
    // ...
    // use va_arg() repeatedly to get the various arguments here
}

void f2(int v1, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, v1);
    f2v(v1, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

And then rework `f1()` to use `f2v()` instead of `f2()`:

```
void f1(int p1, int v1, ...) {
    // do whatever else you need to do before the call to f2

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, v1);
    f2v(v1, args);
    va_end(args);

    // do whatever else you need to do after the call to f2
}
```

This is, in theory, how `printf()` and `vprintf()` work--`printf()` internally can call `vprintf()` so that two functionally identical implementations are not needed.

(Don't forget--you need to `#include <stdarg.h>` to get access to `va_list`, `va_start()`, etc.)

Comment: thanks. This is actually situation I was afraid of. Unfortunately I have no access to f2 and can't rewrite it.

Comment: Then you can't do it in a portable way in C. If you tell us what `f2()` actually is, we may be able to offer alternatives.

Comment: It's a function from an external library (I don't have access to the sources). And I have no alternatives. Thanks anyway.

Comment: As long as you don't have to mess with the arguments (i.e. don't have to, say, strip the first argument), you could do this with a bit of assembly that acts as a trampoline.  It will be neither straightforward nor non-fragile.

Comment: Hence why I said "you can't do it in a *portable* way" -- all bets are off when assembly's involved.

Answer (score 4):

Although you already have accepted a correct answer.

An alternative if you don't have access to `f2` is to use a variadic macro. This is something that is available since C99:

```
#define F1(P1, V1, ...)           \
do {                              \
   /* do something with P1, V1 */ \
   f2(__VA_ARGS__);               \
} while(0)
```

Here the `do`-`while` is just a trick to encapsulate your statements such that a call to that macro may appear anywhere a normal statement would and all the `\` help to write the macro on several lines.

Such macros are a quite commonly used to augment `printf` to print log messages with a prefix, e.g:

```
#define dprintf(...)                               \
do {                                               \
   fprintf(stderr, "%lX: ", (long unsigned)mynum); \
   fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__);                   \
} while(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can not do this. However, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150543/forward-an-invocation-of-a-variadic-function-in-c).